# Better title emphasis in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

There should be some more emphasis on the title of the chat room when the user first joins the chat.  Often there is some useful information about how the room operates in this area.  A specific example being "Can I ask?" questions in chat rooms with titles that clearly say "Just ask your question."  It adds unnecessary cruft and takes away from the conversation as X regulars tell somebody to look at the title.

Perhaps the title and the info about it could simply have some kind of bright border around it for the first *n* seconds or the title comes down in a notification bar, akin to the one received in chat if there was a problem with the internet connection.

Comment: You could put big flashy letters, you could lot the title of the page first and then make the rest of the page appear, you could force the user to write the title of the chatroom before talking first, it wouldn't make much of a difference for some people.